# Database Queue for android SQLite

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

I have an Android Application that holds a fairly large Database which is accessed from multiple threads. I am starting to get Database locked Exceptions. My question, is there a way of creating a database Queue (similar to FMDataBase.Queue in iOS)?

I have done some research and I don't want to create a helper class as a lot of my database queries and inserts are different so creating a method for each query is not feasible.

I could put

```
if(!db.isLocked)
{
    //exec(BLAH)
}
 else
{
  //try{thread.sleep(1000);}... then some retry code
}
```

on every database function but there must be a better way than this.

moreover if the thread is locked after is has slept for 1000ms, it will still crash and if the db is locked for 10ms I will be waiting for 990ms for the query to run, which is not great for user experience.

Is is possible to create a Queue so that any commands sent to the db will be executed once the the db becomes unlocked?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question, is there a way of creating a database Queue

Move all your database writes to an `IntentService`, a regular service hosting a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, a `LinkedBlockingQueue` held by your singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`, etc.

> a lot of my database queries and inserts are different so creating a method for each query is not feasible.

The overhead to wrap a database I/O in a method not especially much, less than what you were proposing doing in your question.

> if the db is locked for 10ms I will be waiting for 990ms for the query to run, which is not great for user experience

Tune your database access (e.g., `EXPLAIN` keyword, then set up appropriate indices). Use Traceview to determine exactly where your problems lie. If your problems are in a database transaction (e.g., you open your own transaction and do a ton of work inside of it), consider [using `yieldIfContendedSafely()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#yieldIfContendedSafely%28%29).

Comment: IntentService is no longer viable on Android O :(

Comment: @MooingDuck: `IntentService` is still viable; it just needs to be in the foreground. We also have other options nowadays: RxJava-based queues, `WorkManager`, etc., in addition to the ones that I mentioned in the answer.