# Issue fetching data in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have two service classes like `Service A` and `Service B` running simultaneously. The two services need SQLite data from a single table. When two queries are executed simultaneously, the application crashes when data is fetched from one table. Here is what I mean:

```
Service A
{
  db.getdata();
}

Service B
{
  db.getdata();
}
```

Is there any way to execute the same query simultaneously on a single table? If so, how?

Comment: show code you have written to fetch data as well as update your query with logs for crash

Comment: check here on how to avoid that -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755142/database-queue-for-android-sqlite -- however i suspect your problem lies somewere else so add the code and error you see in the log cat

Comment: there is no logcat error for this crash.when app get crash app not closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle such errors, its best to use Content Providers,it handles such requests.

If you want to continue using sqlite, create a singleton for ur sqlite object and make calls synchronous

Comment: https://github.com/ikartiks/Capstone-project/blob/master/greVocab/src/main/java/com/kartik/grevocab/persistence/GreVocabDbHelper.java

mark the answer as correct if you find the solution useful

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. Nice one!